# How can I get a class object/instance from a previous __import__ in Python?

Tags: python

Let's suppose you have a module named "module" inside a hirearchical "folder2" with a class named "klass".

How can I get the class like in a square bracket syntax?

```py
module = __import__('folder1.folder2.module', fromlist='*')
sbs_module = module['klass']

#lets say we print a value from the method getValue
print sbs_module.getValue()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line:

```py
sbs_module = module['klass']
```

with this line:

```py
sbs_module = module.klass
```

The reason for that is that you need to refer to module variables (in this case variable named `klass`) by using dot notation, not by accessing the variables by keys.

Alternatively you can use two different notations:

- by key:

  ```py
  sbs_module = vars(module)['klass']
  ```
- by attribute:

  ```py
  sbs_module = getattr(module, 'klass')
  ```

but I do not recommend it unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: I did it by attribute:
    module = __import__('folder1.folder2.module', fromlist='*')
    klass = getattr(module, 'klass')
    print klass.getValue()
And it worked, thank you.